# dynamic vue template using v-if

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Would like to test out vue with jquery. I created two templates in html as per below;

```
<div id="app">
<input type='text' id='test'>
 <template v-if='s'>
  <div>
    A
  </div>
 </template>
<template v-if='t'>
 <div>
   B
 </div>
</template>
</div>
```

Depending on the input value in the textbox - either 's' or 't', I'd like to show the respective template - 'A' or 'B'. My vue settings as per below;

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  s: null,
  t : null
 },
mounted: function() {
var self = this;
var value = $('#test').val('');
  if(value==s) {
    self.s = true;
    self.t = null;
  }
  else if(value==t) {
    self.s = null;
    self.t = true;
  }
  else{
    self.s = null;
    self.t = null;
}
}});
```

I've no luck so far. The code is available in https://jsfiddle.net/fairul82/5zp2d48w/25/

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for such task. Also have you tried to `console.log(value)`?

Comment: yup console.log(value) on textbox input looks good. Any better approach? using v-model

Comment: you generally don't use jQuery anymore if you're using Vue. You might still use jQuery's other functions like their `.ajax` although I'd still recommend you to find a replacement for it e.g. Axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason why you would want to use jQuery? For one your `mounted` function is only going to be executed once the component is mounted. It's not like a watcher where you're constantly monitoring a value. And besides what you're trying to do could simply be achieved like this ..

```
<div id="app">
<input type='text' id='test' v-model="input">

<template v-if="input == 's'">
<div>
A
</div>
</template>
<template v-if="input == 't'">
<div>
B
</div>
</template>
</div>
```

And ..

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: ''
  }
});
```